# How do I only detect back to back duplicate elements from a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to detect back to back duplicates from a list. I have tried different duplicate detections, but I have not been able to crawl through the list and detect back to back duplicates.

`[1,1,2,4,5,6,5]`

only `1` should should be found, `5` should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of the last value you saw and only append to a new list if it's the same as the current value:

```
numbers = [1,1,2,4,5,6,5]
duplicates = []
previous = None
for n in numbers:
    if n == previous:
        duplicates.append(n)
    previous = n
```

You could also use `zip` and slice the list to view the previous items as you loop:

```
duplicates = []
for previous, item in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]):
    if previous == item:
        duplicates.append(item)
```

An equivalent [list comprehension](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/):

```
duplicates = [
    item
    for previous, item in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]
    if previous == item
]
```

Note that these both append duplicates more than once if they appear multiple times in a row.

Answer (score 2):

if consecutive repeated values must be found, I'd use `itertools.groupby`:

```
items = [1,1,2,4,5,6,5]

[g for g, l in itertools.groupby(items) if len(list(l)) > 1]
```

Other way could be by zipping your list and comparing adjacent values:

```
[e1 for e1, e2 in zip(items, items[1:]) if e1 == e2]
```

Answer (score 0):

To find adjacent duplicates you can iterate through your list of items and compare the current one to the next.

```
items = [1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5]

for i, item in enumerate(items):
    # don't compare last item to avoid going out of range
    if i < len(items) - 1:
         if item == items[i + 1]:
             print 'duplicate found', item, items[i + 1]
```

This could be further optimized by removing the last item from the loop. This avoids the need to do an `if` check to make sure we're not on the last item.

```
items = [1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5]

for i, item in enumerate(items[:-1]):
    if item == items[i + 1]:
         print 'duplicate found', item, items[i + 1]
```